# Why is setTimeout/setInterval slowing down when i click onto the page?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, setinterval

I found out that when you use `setInterval()` or loop `setTimeout()` functions and then hold click while moving your cursor on the website (like you do when you want to highlight text), the interval is slowed down for some reason (in Firefox). Sometimes it even slowed down when i just moved the cursor while the interval is running.

Here's an example of a "scroll to top" button that uses `setInterval` in which you can see that: https://jsfiddle.net/6yzhvb07/56/

This seems like no big deal in codes like the one above but when I'm e.g. coding a mobile browsergame, it is a big problem because every long touch input slows the whole game down more than 50% (in Mobile Chrome).

Has anyone encountered that problem yet or know what may cause that?

Comment: I don't see any slow down on my machine. In theory, it shouldn't be slowing down the clock.

Comment: You should read about RAF https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how the javascript runtime engine works. JavaScript doesn't support multithreading. JavaScript uses an EventLoop to keep track of all events happing. If a lot of things is happing events gets stacked up and waits to get proccessed.

If you want to understand exatcly how the event loop works and get details on your answer watch this youtube:

[What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Answer (score 1):

That's just one of the caveats of using `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, they are not supposed to be relied upon for accuracy. This is especially true since the blocking nature of JavaScript's single-threaded event loop makes it impossible to guarantee execution at a specific time. If you need something to happen at a more accurate time then one method would be to do some math with the result of `Date.now()` (the amount of milliseconds since January 1 1970 UTC) and occasionally clear and re-set the timeout/interval.

If you're using it for a game then I would recommend not using either and instead opt for `requestAnimationFrame`. This will require you to get the difference in time between frames to mathematically account for any changes.